# How to count vowels and consonants

Tags: swift

I'm currently using Xcode 10.1 and am trying to count the amount of vowels and consonants in my given sentence. I declare the constant globally

```
let sentence = "Here is my sentence"
```

Then I attempt to call a function with a parameter by the name of `"sentenceInput"` that under a certain case adds the sentence to the function which is mean to count the amount of vowels and consonants and return the Int values. However when the function is called I'm told that there is only `1` consonant and `0` vowels. Being new to programming and Xcode in general I would very much appreciate the help. Thank you. Code for function:

```
func findVowelsConsonantsPunctuation(sentenceInput: String) -> (Int, Int, Int) {
    var vowels = 0; var consonants = 0; var punctuation = 0
    for character in sentenceInput.characters{
        switch String(character).lowercased
        {
    case "a", "e", "i", "o", "u":
        vowels += 1
    case ".","!",":",";","?", " ", "'", "":
        punctuation += 1
    default:
        consonants += 1
        }
    return (vowels, consonants, punctuation)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post code that actually compiles. What version of Swift are you using? This has many errors under Xcode 10/Swift 4.2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest reading up on [`Set`](https://www.codingexplorer.com/swift-set-type/).

With that in mind, you could use `CharacterSet` and create 3 sets.

```
// Make your vowels
let vowels = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "aeiouy")
let consonants = CharacterSet.letters.subtracting(vowels)
let punctuation = CharacterSet.punctuationCharacters
```

Then, you'd want to track the counts of vowels, consonants, and punctuation:

```
// Make your vowels
let vowels = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "aeiouy")
let consonants = CharacterSet.letters.subtracting(vowels)
let punctuation = CharacterSet.punctuationCharacters
```

Then, loop through through it.

```
func sentenceComponents(string: String) -> (Int, Int, Int) {
    // Make your vowels
    let vowels = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "aeiouy")
    let consonants = CharacterSet.letters.subtracting(vowels)
    let punctuation = CharacterSet.punctuationCharacters

    // Set up vars to track our coutns
    var vowelCount = 0
    var consonantCount = 0
    var punctuationCount = 0

    string.forEach { char in
        // Make a set of one character
        let set = CharacterSet(charactersIn: String(char))
        // If the character is a member of a set, incremennt the relevant var
        if set.isSubset(of: vowels) { vowelCount += 1 }
        if set.isSubset(of: consonants) { consonantCount += 1 }
        if set.isSubset(of: punctuation) { punctuationCount += 1 }
    }

    return (vowelCount, consonantCount, punctuationCount)
}

let testString = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."

sentenceComponents(string: testString)
```

**Update: Neater & Easier Read (Maybe?)**

I can't stand unlabeled tuples, so here's an update with a `typealias` that tells you what you've got without having to go over the river & through the woods to figure out what's what in the tuple:

```
typealias SentenceComponents = (vowels: Int, consonants: Int, punctuation: Int)

func components(in string: String) -> SentenceComponents {
    // Make your vowels
    let vowels = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "aeiouy")
    let consonants = CharacterSet.letters.subtracting(vowels)
    let punctuation = CharacterSet.punctuationCharacters

    // Set up vars to track our coutns
    var vowelCount = 0
    var consonantCount = 0
    var punctuationCount = 0

    string.forEach { char in
        // Make a set of one character
        let singleCharSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: String(char))
        // If the character is a member of a set, incremennt the relevant var
        if singleCharSet.isSubset(of: vowels) { vowelCount += 1 }
        if singleCharSet.isSubset(of: consonants) { consonantCount += 1 }
        if singleCharSet.isSubset(of: punctuation) { punctuationCount += 1 }
    }

    return (vowelCount, consonantCount, punctuationCount)
}

let testString = "Smokey, this is not 'Nam. This is bowling. There are rules."

// (vowels 17, consonants 27, punctuation 5)
components(in: testString)
```

Comment: Very good answer. SentenceComponents is great idea, it could be struct though. `CharacterSet`s are the way to go in this solution for sure, great on that too. However, there are several issues with this solution: `y` is not a vowel in English language; consonants characterSet: `CharacterSet.letters` contains not only latin character (for instance all cyrillic symbols are included); vowels contain only lowercase symbols(A for instance won't be counted correctly). In conclusion: 1) remove `y` from vowels; 2) define consonants explicitly; 3) call `lowercased()` on string, before the forEach.

Answer (score 1):

Try this below.  You had your `return` statement within your for-loop.  Thus you're returning after the first iteration.  I also moved your `lowercased()` above the for-loop.  That way it's less processing time to lowercase the character every iteration.

```
func findVowelsConsonantsPunctuation(sentenceInput: String) -> (Int, Int, Int) {
    var vowels = 0; var consonants = 0; var punctuation = 0
    sentenceInput = sentenceInput.lowercased()
    for character in sentenceInput.characters {
        switch character {
        case 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u':
            vowels += 1
        case '.','!',':',';','?', ' ', '\'', '':
            punctuation += 1
        default:
            consonants += 1
        }

    }
    return (vowels, consonants, punctuation)
}
```

Comment: @rmaddy Is it because of the `switch` line?

Answer (score 1):

You put your `return` statement inside the loop, so the first time the loop code executes, the function will return. That is why there will only be one consonant since the switch case statement is only executed once.

You need to put your `return` statement **outside** the loop, like this:

```
func findVowelsConsonantsPunctuation(sentenceInput: String) -> (Int, Int, Int) {
    var vowels = 0
    var consonants = 0
    var punctuation = 0
    for character in sentenceInput.characters {
        switch String(character).lowercase {
    case "a", "e", "i", "o", "u":
        vowels += 1
    case ".","!",":",";","?", " ", "'", "":
        punctuation += 1
    default:
        consonants += 1
        }
    }
    return (vowels, consonants, punctuation)
}
```

Comment: This is why the OP needs to post real code. With the `return` where it was it doesn't even compile. And that's just one of the many errors.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes, I did not even realize that! The OP probably messed up his/her copy/pasting code into the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
func findVowelsConsonants (_ sentence: String)-> (Int, Int){
            let sentenceLowercase = sentence.lowercased()
            var tuple = (numberOfVowels: 0, numberOfConsonants: 0, numberOfPunctuation: 0)
            for char in sentenceLowercase{
                switch char{
                case "a", "e", "i", "o", "u":
                    tuple.0 += 1
                case "b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z":
                    tuple.1 += 1
                default:
                    tuple.2 += 1
                }
            }
            return (tuple.0, tuple.1)
        }
```